# Load an image into draw loop in Processingjs

Tags: javascript, processing

My bee won't show up. What is the proper way to load and display an image in the draw loop?

```
/* @pjs preload="/static/uploaded_resources/p.8706/Flower-Ice-icon.png"; */
/* @pjs preload="/static/uploaded_resources/p.8706/bee.png"; */
void setup() {  // this is run once.   

    PImage img;
    PImage bee;
    // set the background color
    background(255);

    // canvas size (Variable aren't evaluated. Integers only, please.)
    size(256, 256); 

    img = loadImage("/static/uploaded_resources/p.8706/Flower-Ice-icon.png");
    bee = loadImage("/static/uploaded_resources/p.8706/bee.png");
    image(img, 0, 0);
} 
void draw() {  // this is run repeatedly.  
    image(bee, mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

Here's a link to the sketch: http://studio.sketchpad.cc/sp/pad/view/VfC92Mrf5o/rev.119

Comment: I'd have to see the translated js code to be sure, but I bet it's a scoping issue. Try moving the `PImage` declarations outside both functions.

Comment: Oh, happy pollination! http://studio.sketchpad.cc/sp/pad/view/VfC92Mrf5o/rev.152

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using multiple preloads is not supported by Pjs. Instead, you'll want to comma-separate those two images as argument to a single preload command. See http://processingjs.org/reference/preload, "Syntax for multiple images"

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot for another sketch I'm working on http://studio.sketchpad.cc/sp/pad/view/9QiGOX61ks/rev.244 Is Processingjs still in active development?

Comment: we're trying to get some code in to be on par with the upcoming Processing 2.0 API, but we don't have as many devs as we used to, so it's taking longer between releases now.